# SQL Server 2012 not using allocated memory

Tags: sql-server-2012, memory

I have an issue with a SQL Server 2012 SP2 std server on a windows 2012 64-bit server

Even though I have assigned SQL Server 12GB of RAM - it won't use more than ~700MB
I've simulated memory load under windows and the VM uses the RAM as it should, but if I simulate load under SQL Server it never goes above ~700MB.

I'm using this to report SQL Server memory usage:

```
SELECT
(physical_memory_in_use_kb/1024) AS Memory_usedby_Sqlserver_MB
FROM sys.dm_os_process_memory;
```

The DB's have been moved to this server from SQL Server 2008 which never had this issue.

The app hasn't changed - apart from running really slowly now :/

Any suggestions please?

Thanks

Comment: Is there a max memory assigned to SQL? Can you provide the output to this query:
SELECT name, value, value_in_use, [description] 
FROM sys.configurations
WHERE name like '%server memory%'
ORDER BY name

Comment: Thanks Greg, max server memory (MB) 12288 12288 Maximum size of server memory (MB)
min server memory (MB) 0 16 Minimum size of server memory (MB)

Comment: SQL Server will use what it needs. It is possible that your data is only 700MBs and does not require any more data to run queries.

Comment: Is anything else installed on the server? Does sql have lock pages in memory privilege? Are there any messages in the error log about memory being paged out?

Comment: Thanks Greg & Erik - there are 18 Databases which are roughly 300MB each. I would have expected that the server cache would grow to the 12GB overtime - the old SQL2008 did. I do have lock pages set for the SQL service account and have autO_close disabled. Actually I've been hitting it with SQLqueryStress testing for 20 minutes and have gotten the memory up to 1860MB - a new record! Could it be that sql2012 is more stingy/effective with RAM than 2008 and the lack of RAM usage isn't related to the poor performance of the app?

Comment: Where are you seeing this 700 MB? Task manager? Stop looking there, it’s a filthy liar.